# Is there a built in python method for double slashing file paths?

Tags: python

When giving file paths to a Python script I find myself constantly having to manually double slash the file path (because of escape characters). My question: is there an in-built python function/class/method that either signify escape characters do not apply to the string in question or will simply double slash the paths for me?

i.e.

```
D:\MPhil\Model_Building\Models\TGFB\Vilar2006\Another_Fit_test\Fit15
```

into:

```
D:\\MPhil\\Model_Building\\Models\\TGFB\\Vilar2006\\Another_Fit_test\\Fit15
```

Comment: Use raw string `r` prefix  or just use forward slashes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting File Paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652498/formatting-file-paths)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prefix your string with r like this:

```
some_path = r"escape\codes\will\be\bypassed"
```

Comment: Perfect - knew there must be an easy way. Thanks